# How to check if a number is zero?

Tags: c++, types

```
if(number == 0) {
 //do something
}
```

Since zero evaluates to false in C++, if a number is zero it will be false in if condition.
how can I check if it is really a number zero?

Comment: Your code is fine. When `number` is `0`, `number == 0` is `1`, which is true.

Comment: Your code will work. Test it.

Comment: Yes, I think I got the wrong question...

Comment: You should delete the question to save your reputation :)

Comment: @GreenAsJade the OP can experienxe troubles with floats/doubles

Comment: @FelicePollano He didn't mention that. You're assuming his question is about float/double.. That might not be the case.

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun I'm assuming the OP is aking because he actually have a proble, and floating point is the case.

Answer (score 2):

There is a misconception, here: the `if` statement is not about the `0` constant or the value of `number`, but about the returned value of `operator==`.

The point is not if number or 0 are themselves equivalent to "false", but if `==` returns true or not. And it returns true if the operands have the same value.

As far integral types promotions work, the above assertion works for whatever pair of integral types.

If `number` is something else, then all relates to the convertibility towards a common type between `number` and `int` (since 0 is a n int) and to the "precision" the `number` value may have, or in the way `operator==` is implemented  between the two types.

Answer (score 0):

You can experience some trouble if `number` is a floating point. If this is your case, just compare with a reasonable small around of zero. Have a look at this article http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/ I'm sure you can better understand the problem.
Trivial example:

```
#define epsilon 0.0001;
if( fabs(number) < epsilon ){
   ....
}
```

choosing the correct epsilon could be tricky, depending on the application.